# Swift iOS: Save QR code from server to apple wallet

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, wallet

It is possible to save a downloaded QR-code from the server into apple wallet?

Thank you

Comment: Read https://itechroof.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/apple-wallet-part-13/

Comment: Your question as it stands does not make a lot of sense.  Do you want to create a pass that bears the QR-Code?  Wallet is not a repository of QR codes, it contains cards and passes only.  Passes can bear a barcode, but it does not have to be a QR code (PDF417, Aztec and Code128 are also supported).

Comment: Thank you guys. I agree with you, it doesn't make sense but that was a requirement basically. I'll inform you for any solution from my side.